# Jump to a certain cell in Syncfusion Spreadsheet Control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, syncfusion

I'm using Winforms C# and I would like to add the Syncfusion Spreadsheet Control.
I would like to ask, it is possible to jump to a certain cell in the control form from another form?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling the SyncfusionAPI to create the cell?

Comment: The Syncfusion Spreadsheet Control will use an already made excel file, so when I click the first form to open the second form (with the Syncfusion Control) should jump/select a certain cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using forms loaded events and Spreadsheet.WorkbookLoaded events are shown below,

**Form1.CS**

```
button1.Click += Button1_Click;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    Form2 frm = new Form2();

    frm.Show();

    this.Hide();

}
```

**Form2.CS**

```
this.Load += Form2_Load;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    try

    {

        var fileStream = new FileStream(@"..\..\Data\Filtering.xlsx", FileMode.Open);

        spreadsheet.Open(fileStream);          

    }

    catch

    {

 

    }

    spreadsheet.WorkbookLoaded += Spreadsheet_WorkbookLoaded;

}

 

private void Spreadsheet_WorkbookLoaded(object sender, Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Helpers.WorkbookLoadedEventArgs args)

{

    //Moves current cell to the mentioned row and column index of the cell,

    spreadsheet.ActiveGrid.CurrentCell.MoveCurrentCell(5, 5);

 

    //For moving the current cell to a different sheet,

    spreadsheet.SetActiveSheet("Sheet1");

    spreadsheet.ActiveGrid.CurrentCell.MoveCurrentCell(6, 5);

}
```